# Traefik having troubles with routing routes with partially overlapping names and rewrite rules

Tags: traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having troubles with setting up ingress routes with rewrite.
My ingress definitions:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mw-abcd
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abcd/v1
        backend:
          serviceName: mw-abcd-v1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /abcd/v2
        backend:
          serviceName: mw-abcd-v2
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mw-abcd-backward-comp
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /abcd/v1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abcd
        backend:
          serviceName: mw-abcd-v1
          servicePort: 80
```

What I want to achieve here is that every request without `/v1` suffix should be redirected to the backend with this suffix and the ones including version should be routed as is. What happens is that the ones with `/v1` are redirected to `/v1/v1` anyway. So the priority is to grab the second rule as first. I've tried to setup priorities manually by proper annotations:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mw-abcd
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/priority: "1"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abcd/v1
        backend:
          serviceName: mw-abcd-v1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /abcd/v2
        backend:
          serviceName: mw-abcd-v2
          servicePort: 80

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mw-abcd-backward-comp
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /abcd/v1
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/priority: "2"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abcd
        backend:
          serviceName: mw-abcd-v1
          servicePort: 80
```

but then everything is going to default backend and retruning 404.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer here. According to the documentation about priorities (https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#priorities):

> By default, routes will be sorted (in descending order) using rules length (to avoid path overlap): PathPrefix:/foo;Host:foo.com (length == 28) will be matched before PathPrefixStrip:/foobar (length == 23) will be matched before PathPrefix:/foo,/bar (length == 20).

I was setting the priorities in wwrong way, the specified number must be big enough (bigger than length of other routes) to overwrite the default behavior. So I ended up with `priority` values like `90` and `100`.